# Translating an Enhanced For Loop into a Standard Loop

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

I always have had trouble translating an enhanced `for` loop into a standard `for` loop. Here is the enhanced `for` loop that I want to change into a standard `for` loop structure:

```
for (Thing cp: getPerson().getEnemy().getMinions())
    {
        if (cp.canMoveTo(this.getLocation()) && cp.getLocation() != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

How can I change this into a standard `for` loop?

Comment: What is the return type of `getMinions()`?

Answer (score 3):

The [enhanced `for` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) can loop through arrays and any kind of [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) object, so the answer depends on whether `getMinions` returns an array or an `Iterable` object.

If it returns an array, then:

```
Thing[] minions = getPerson().getEnemy().getMinions();
for (int i = 0; i < minions.length; ++i) {
    Thing cp = minions[i];
    // ...
}
```

If it returns an `Iterable`, then:

```
Iterator<Thing> it = getPerson().getEnemy().getMinions().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Thing cp = it.next();
    // ...
}
```